# Adding a selenium - rubygems test to azure dev-ops pipeline

Tags: ruby, selenium, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our team has implemented Azure dev-ops and they asked me to add our selenium automation to the pipe-line.  I have found some guides for adding scripts written in .Net to the pipeline but nothing in regards to our scripts written in Ruby.  Is it even possible to add Selenium scripts to the pipeline or must I start writing in .Net?

Since dev-ops is new to me and the team I'm only in the research phase of this process.  I have not found a clear answer to my problem so I want to see if anyone has ever added selenium with ruby to the pipeline.  My goal is to have the scripts automatically execute once code is pushed to the test environment.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but have you looked at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/ruby?view=vsts) link already?

Comment: No I didn't see that link.  I was reviewing the Ui testing documentation and didn't even think about looking at the languages section.  I'll read through the documentation and let everyone know how it goes.  Thanks

Comment: I'm on hold for a few days.  I have to modify a few of my scripts prior to spending time on learning my initial question.  I'll get back to this post as soon as I finish my other tasks.

Comment: An update:  As of this morning I am executing several bat files (hopefully soon to be powershells) that execute the installation of a gem I need in my script, and one that initiates the IEDriverServer.exe.  However my script fails because it is unable to find the standalone server.  So I need to understand how to initiate the selenium standalone server in a devops agent.

Comment: I made more progress but I experienced other problems so I decided to step back from trying to get my automation scripts entered into the pipeline and tried to get the simple "Enter text into google search box" test.  I figured the code for this is simple and I'll hard code all the objects instead of calling object libraries.  In this scenario I'm able to get as far as I did with my other script last night.  And that is the code seems to work until it tried to send_text and then I receive an error.  So now I need to resolve the simple fact that I cannot enter text into the field.

Comment: Update:  I've been pushed away from trying to implement the Selenium Ruby scripts and begin using c#.  So I've been writing (to the best of my abilities) scripts in Visual Studio using C# and then adding the Solution I created to the Pipeline. The simple scripts work successfully, however my more complex scripts fail and that can be due to skill level in C#. I'm trying to copy a folder I have in my solution and then zip it up.  That zip file is then uploaded into the system via website.  I do not believe the zip file is being created when I execute the test on the Virtual Server in thePipeline